# google api file upload response requires Authorization

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-api

I am trying to upload a file using google apis. But i am getting a response login required. How can i solve this? Any one can help me to come of this? And below is the response for it.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

Comment: You need to be Authenticated before you can use more of the Google APIs.  Try checking the API documentation under authorization. More then likely you can log in using OAuth2, or a service account.

Comment: thanks for the response Mr. DalmTo. can i have that url to find the authorization?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Comment: u know this "The content of the form does not meet the conditions specified in the policy document." error code? It is asking InvalidPolicyDocument code.